# How can I calculate the z-transformation of this transfer function of a time-discrete controller?

Tags: control-theory, transfer-function

I am currently preparing for an exam where on part is control theory. This is one task from a former exam where I don't know how to solve it (translated from German):

> Calculate the z-transformed transfer function $G(z)$ of the time-discrete plant ("Ersatzregelstrecke"). The time-continous plant $G_s(s)$ is given. The sampling rate $T_A$ should be viewed as given.
>
> $$G_s(s) = \frac{1}{s^2 + 2s + 1}$$
>
> Note: $$\mathcal{Z} \left \{\frac{a^2}{s \cdot (s+a)^2} \right\} = \frac{z}{z-1} - \frac{z}{z-e^{-aT}} - \frac{aTz \cdot e^{-aT}}{(z-e^{-aT})^2}$$

I know that I can simplify $G_s(s) = \frac{1}{(s+1)^2}$, but this is obviously not of the form $\frac{a^2}{s \cdot (s+a)^2}$...

How can I calculate this?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, the correct solution is $\frac {e^{-a \cdot T_A} \cdot T_A \cdot z} {(z-e^{-a \cdot T_A})^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to solve it, you have to divide $ G_s(s)$ by s first and then you have it in the form on which you can perform the Z-transform.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that $G(s)$ is formed by $$\frac{1}{s^2} \to \frac{1}{(s+1)^2}$$ with the corresponding Z-transform/Laplace pairs $$\frac{1}{s^2} \to \frac{Tz}{(z-1)^2}$$ and $$\frac{1}{s+a} \to \frac{z}{z-e^{-aT}}$$
With this information you should be able to make the conversion adhering to all the rules of linearity, e.t.c, thats if you wanna find the representation from scratch.
Found this: A more elegant way is to go back to the time domain and compute the Z-transform sum. Or just use the tables that have become very popular [Table of Laplace and Z Transforms](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/LaplaceZTable/LaplaceZFuncTable.html).